# How to parse MS Word document by style with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-style

I'm trying to go through a MSWord document and pull out all the paragraphs with the Style, "Question" and then reprint them at the end of the document. Any suggestions would be super helpful - here's what I have (I think all the steps are there I'm just having trouble with VBA formatting).

```
Sub PullQuestions()
    '
    ' PullQuestions Macro
    '
    '
    Dim curPar As Paragraph

    ' numLists = ActiveDocument.ListParagraphs.Count

    ' reprints each question on a new line at end of document'
    For Each curPar In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        If curPar.Selection.Style = "Question" Then
            Selection.TypeText (curPar & vbCr)
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: do you want to copy the whole paragraphs (including styles, etc.) at the end or you need to reprint only text there?

Answer (score 3):

I think you'll find the search function is probably more efficient for you.  The following code will search the document and put the values into an array and then put them at the end of the document.  It'll also set the paragraph style to reflect the original.  Be aware you'll get a nasty output if you keep running it with the styles applied to the output at the end of the document.

I've commented it fairly well but let me know if it doesn't make sense.

```
Sub SearchStyles()
    Dim iCount As Integer, iArrayCount As Integer, bFound As Boolean

    'We'll store our result in an array so set this up (assume 50 entries)
    ReDim sArray(1 To iArrayCount) As String
    iArrayCount = 50

    'State your Style type
    sMyStyle = "Heading 1"

    'Always start at the top of the document
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory

    'Set your search parameters and look for the first instance
    With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchKashida = False
        .MatchDiacritics = False
        .MatchAlefHamza = False
        .MatchControl = False
        .MatchByte = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchFuzzy = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Style = sMyStyle
        .Execute
    End With

    'If we find one then we can set off a loop to keep checking
    'I always put a counter in to avoid endless loops for one reason or another
    Do While Selection.Find.Found = True And iCount < 1000
        iCount = iCount + 1

        'If we have a result then add the text to the array
        If Selection.Find.Found Then
            bFound = True

            'We do a check on the array and resize if necessary (more efficient than resizing every loop
            If ii Mod iArrayCount = 0 Then ReDim Preserve sArray(1 To UBound(sArray) + iArrayCount)
            sArray(iCount) = Selection.Text

            'Reset the find parameters
            Selection.Find.Execute
        End If
    Loop

    'Finalise the array to the actual size
    ReDim Preserve sArray(1 To iCount)

    If bFound Then
        'Output to the end of the document
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\EndOfDoc").Range.Select
        Selection.TypeParagraph
        For ii = LBound(sArray) To UBound(sArray)
            Selection.Text = sArray(ii)
            Selection.Range.Style = sMyStyle
            Selection.MoveRight wdCharacter, 1
            If ii < UBound(sArray) Then Selection.TypeParagraph
        Next ii
    End If
End Sub
```